# Least Squares SVR regression in Python

Tags: python, regression, svm, least-squares

I'm looking for a library in Python which models the Least Squares Support Vector Machines Regression algorithm (LS-SVR).

I know there exists one for classification, see https://pypi.org/project/FukuML/, but I'm interested in one for the regression case.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try this one http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html

Comment: sklearn.svm does not offer a LS-SVR approach. I guess you're thinking of the linear kernel, which is present in this package, but is unfortunately not the same method as LS-SVR.